# Is it possible to send the picture through the socket in android

Tags: android, sockets, video, image

Not only one or two picture but a lot of picture to make it as a video at some frame rate

and pass it through the socket and let the other android device build the picture real-time

Answer (score 1):

Possible?  Yes, provided you use either wifi or an intermediate server, as most mobile networks effectively have firewalls which won't permit incoming connections, so the phones cannot directly initiate communication with each other.

Useful?  You would probably not get a tolerable rate/resolution without compression.

In terms of doing it, the networking part is fully standard once your application has internet permission in its manifest.  The Android unique parts consist of obtaining and displaying frames, and any use you chose to make of built in encoders/decoders.